# ArcSDESQLExecute: How to return column names from queries?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, sql, oracle-dbms, fields-attributes

I have an [ArcSDESQLExecute](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/python/executing-sql-using-an-arcsde-connection.htm) python script:

```
import sys
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = sys.path[0]
egdb_conn = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(r"Database Connections\Connection1.sde")
sql_statement = """
SELECT * FROM USER1.A_TEST_TABLE_1;
SELECT * FROM USER1.A_TEST_TABLE_2
"""
sql_statement_list = sql_statement.split(";")
for sql in sql_statement_list:
    print(sql)
    egdb_return = egdb_conn.execute(sql)
    for row in egdb_return:
        print(("{:<15}"*len(row)).format(*row))
```

The script allows me to execute SQL statements, and return the result sets to the python window.

Here's an example of a result set output:

```
SELECT * FROM USER1.A_TEST_TABLE_1
<-------------- No column names --------------->
1              1              APPLE          0.1            
2              2              PEAR           0.2            
3              3              BANANA         0.3            
4              4              MANGO          0.4            
5              5              ORANGE         0.5            
6              6              BLUEBERRY      0.6            
7              7              STRAWBERRY     0.7            
8              8              RASPBERRY      0.8            
9              9              KIWI           0.9            
10             10             PINEAPPLE      1.0
```

As you can see, the result set that is returned doesn't include column names (`OBJECTID`, `ID`, `TYPE`, `COST`).

How can I include column names in the result set from ArcSDESQLExecute? (Is the ArcPy.ArcSDESQLExecute `execute` method capable of returning such information?)

Comment: This is one of the reasons "SELECT *" is so dangerous.  If you provide a column list, you'll know what is in the return columns.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  `ArcGISSQLExecute()` is getting your database to execute actual SQL - ArcGIS is doing very little here.  As a result the SQL required will be specific to your RDBMS.  If you don't know your columns (and specify them in your query) then you'll need to query one of the system tables that records the columns to get that list.

Comment: You could always use `arcpy.ListFields()`

Comment: I've removed my cross-post after reading your two questions a few more times. The SO question has far more than an MCVE so I had to do some looking past the try/excepts and ArcPy pieces.

Comment: @Wilson why do you provide one variable containing multiple SQL statements and then split it?  Why not provide as a list of statements to loop through (just removes the need for the split line).  Are you using the entire `sql_statement` variable elsewhere, or only in the split state?

Comment: @Midavalo You make a good point. I took the script directly from the documentation. I'm surprised ESRI didn't do this in the original script. Maybe they did it so that it's dead easy to paste in [multiple SQL statements](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/example-discovering-domain-usage.htm). Kind of like you can do in SQL Plus or SQL Developer. You can just run a long list of scripts that are separated by a semicolon. I'm not good with python yet, so I haven't tackled it. But I'll look into it - thanks.

Comment: @Wilson correct my query has nothing to do with this question, I was just curious.  You can "multi-line" a list so that each query appears on a different line for your "dead easy to paste in multiple SQL statements" but your way still works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcSDESQLExecute does not return column names in the result, only the values in a list of lists where each list is a row of values returned from the table.

My guess is this is because when working with this data in arcpy you would typically want just values returned as you would then be using them elsewhere in your python as variables for other tools.  Having the column names in there would make these variables a lot harder to work with (as you'd have to remove them from the result when working with those values.

One way you could handle this is to fetch the column names first (using `arcpy.ListFields()` or `arcpy.Describe().fields` and then pass that to the SQL query

```
>>> myColumns = [c.name for c in arcpy.ListFields(r'Database Connections\GISSE.sde\gisse.DBO.TestPoints') if c.name != 'SHAPE']
>>> print myColumns
 [u'OBJECTID', u'MyField1', u'MyField2', u'MyField3']

>>> sqlquery = """ select {} from testpoints """.format(', '.join(myColumns))
>>> print sqlquery
 select OBJECTID, MyField1, MyField2, MyField3 from testpoints

>>> sqlconn.execute(sqlquery)
 [[2, u'One', u'new value', None]]
```

If you need to have the columns returned as part of your query, you could look at `pyodbc` or `pymssql` or `cx_oracle` which offer a bit more around what you can return from your query.  `pyodbc` definitely has the ability to return column names - see [return column names from pyodbc execute() statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704305/return-column-names-from-pyodbc-execute-statement) from SO, and the [pyodbc docs](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/Cursor.wiki)

```
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
```

I am not familiar with `cx_oracle` as I don't use Oracle, so not sure how it's done with that or if there is a better tool for accessing Oracle from python.

These other methods, however, will not allow you to simply pass a `.sde` connection file so you would need to provide connection details in your python script.  This was for me the reason I switched to using ArcSDESQLExecute.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a variation of Midavalo's answer:

```
import sys
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = sys.path[0]
conn_path = "Database Connections\\Connection1.sde\\"
table_name = "USER1.A_TEST_TABLE"
egdb_conn = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(conn_path)

columns = [c.name for c in arcpy.ListFields(conn_path + table_name) if c.name != 'SHAPE']
sql_statement = """select {} from """.format(', '.join(columns)) + table_name

print sql_statement
print ("")
print(("{:<15}"*len(columns)).format(*columns))

egdb_return = egdb_conn.execute(sql_statement)
for row in egdb_return:
    print(("{:<15}"*len(row)).format(*row))
```

---

```
select OBJECTID, ID, TYPE, COST from USER1.A_TEST_TABLE

OBJECTID       ID             TYPE           COST           
1              1              APPLE          0.1            
2              2              PEAR           0.2            
3              3              BANANA         0.3            
4              4              MANGO          0.4            
5              5              ORANGE         0.5            
6              6              BLUEBERRY      0.6            
7              7              STRAWBERRY     0.7            
8              8              RASPBERRY      0.8            
9              9              KIWI           0.9            
10             10             PINEAPPLE      1.0
```

*Note: I'm not good with Python yet, so suggestions or edits are welcome.*

Comment: My python suggestion: Learn about [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/) - `""" select {} from {} """.format(', '.join(columns), table_name)`

Comment: @Midavalo Any experience with line breaks in python? My Stack Overflow question here: [Python script that executes SQL: How to preserve formatting of SQL text when creating a VIEW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872270/python-script-that-executes-sql-how-to-preserve-formatting-of-sql-text-when-cre?noredirect=1#comment74780202_43872270)